# installing new coldfusion 2016 and website broken

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-2016

I installed the new ColdFusion version 2016, and have it and the old ColdFusion 10 version both installed on different ports. However, when I browse the site, both give me the same error:

> http://localhost:8550/workingcart/js/fancyBox/jquery.fancybox.css
>
> **HTTP Status 404 -
>   /workingcart/js/fancyBox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css**
>
> **type** Status report
>
> **message** /workingcart/js/fancyBox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css
>
> **description** The requested resource is not available.
>       Apache Tomcat/8.0.27

even if the file exists on the file system. I checked google, looked at couple of forums, but could not find a way to fix it. Does anyone know how to resolve it?

The site does load, but **only, if I supply `index.cfm` to end of the url. Otherwise, it shows the same error**, but it does not load internal files.

Comment: ColdFusions' built in server is case sensitive, might that be an issue?

Comment: Probably more a question for ServerFault.

Comment: The files doesn't simply need to be present in the file system, it has to be a) web browseable on that *URL* (the file path is only tangentially related); b) by the web server that's serving it. So your website for the CF2016 install needs to have a URL /workingcart/js/fancyBox/jquery.fancybox.css in *its* webroot. You don't mention anything about ensuring or checking this, so presume you haven't. What directory is CF2016's wwwroot, and within that, is there a /workingcart/js/fancyBox/jquery.fancybox.css?

Comment: my website is in `cfusion/wwwroot/workingcart/js/fancyBox/jquery.fancybox.css`

Comment: You are try to access http://localhost:8550/workingcart/js/fancyBox/jquery.fancybox.css and error shows 404 for /workingcart/js/fancyBox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css. Is the first url making a reference to the second link, in any way?

Comment: Are you trying to browse a stylesheet?

Comment: @Dan, can you share a repro code?

Comment: if you are on linux / mac. check file owner ship and permissions. also make sure that a tomcat servlet or filter is not hijacking your .css files. (a test would be to just rename you .css file to .cfm to see if you still get the 404. For tomcat the catalina.out log may also give some clues.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.  Definitely has to do with Case Sensitivity on the path to my CSS and JQuery. Check your path on the  tag and  tags. It worked for me.

For example:

Old Code:
link href="/phonestore/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"

New Code:
link href="/PhoneStore/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"